# How to tell `git diff` to make a diff usable with `patch -p0`?

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff

I have a file in a git repo. I checked it out from branch **release**, edited it to fix a problem, and checked it in to a new branch **bugfix**. I now want to make a diff file which captures this edit. I want to apply this diff file, using `patch -p0`, to a separate copy of the **release** branch, which is outside of git control. After the patch, I want the file to match what I have in branch **bugfix**.

I tried using the command `git diff release bugfix -- myfile.m4`. It gave me a .diff file which begins,

```
index 17641f7482..2b31725fae 100644
--- a/myfile.m4
+++ b/myfile.m4
[… rest of diff elided …]
```

When I apply this diff to my separate repo using `patch -p0`, it fails. Patch is unable to find paths `a/myfile.m4` and `b/myfile.m4`, because of course they don't exist. There are no directories `a` and `b` in my source. Note, if I could use `patch -p1`, then the diff would work as a patch. But, because of tooling constraints, I am not easily able to use `patch -p1`.

I would like the .diff file to leave out the `a/` and `b/` prefixes. I would like the diff file to read something like:

```
index 87641f7482..2821725fae 100644
--- myfile.m4
+++ myfile.m4
[… rest of diff elided …]
```

Is there a way to make **git diff** produce a diff without those non-existent path prefixes?

There is a workaround: checkout the file from the **release** branch, rename it `myfile.m4.orig`, then checkout the modified file from the **bugfix** branch, then do `diff -u myfile.m4.orig myfile.m4`. This gives me a diff which I can use with `patch -p0`. But I want to avoid making a separate file with a contrived file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--dst-prefix=` and `--src-prefix=` to specify the destination and source prefixes, I guess that you might be able to set them to an empty string:

```
$ git diff --src-prefix= --dst-prefix= release bugfix -- myfile.m4
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can also use `--no-prefix`:

```
$ git diff --no-prefix release bugfix -- myfile.m4
```

Comment: Yes, this works!  It also helped me find the option `--no-prefix`, which works just as well but more elegantly. Maybe edit your answer to use this instead?

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt thanks for the info, I have updated the post :-)